# Expansion, reduction and removal of redundant terms in truth table

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, boolean-algebra

[image: Truth table from left to right]

What steps take left truth-table to right truth-table? In general, what are general rules to follow in transformations of truth-table?

Comment: ... I am not quite clear what you are being asked to do here ... what does the 'into' mean?

Comment: Hi Bram28, 'into' means that we start from left-side truth table and by series of expansion, reduction, and removal of redundant cubes, take it to right-side truth table.

Comment: I guess you already know that Steps 1 and 2 are output expansions, 3 is an input reduction, 4 is an input expansion, and so on.  Correct?  Are you looking for an explanation for why each step (some steps) are admissible?

Comment: Hi Fabio, Yes I am looking for an explanation of choosing a particular output expansion, and input reduction. I know there are steps; I wish to know underlying logic to do so. How do I decide that I should take particular output expansion, and not choose something other? Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: @Digvijay. Hmm, I'm not familiar with this method, and I must say I cannot follow the steps ... sorry! :(

Comment: I am looking for an explanation behind choice of each step. How to decide that first step should be output expansion, and not input reduction? Please clarify underlying logic in choosing steps.

Answer (score 0):

While it is not possible to infer the precise algorithm from one example, it's a reasonable bet to assume that we are looking at some variation of the Espresso algorithm.  A reasonably short explanation can be found in R. Rudell, A. Sangiovanni-Vincentelli, *Multiple-Valued Minimization for PLA Optimization*, IEEE Transactions on CAD, vol. CAD-6, No 5, Sep. 1987, pp. 727-750.  The longer version (without multi-valued extensions) is in R. Brayton, G. Hachtel, C. McMullen, A. Sangiovanni-Vincentelli, *Logic Minimization Algorithms for VLSI Synthesis*, Kluwer, 1984.

The basic idea of the Espresso algorithm, and in part of its variants and predecessors (e.g., Hong and Ostapko's MINI), is to alternate three operations: reduction, expansion, and elimination of redundant cubes.

Espresso (you may still be able to find the C code of Rick Rudell's implementation around) is a rather sophisticated heuristic-search algorithm.  The sophistication is needed to get a good chance to climb out of local minima.  To give an example, in the irredundancy step, Espresso solves a minimum set-cover problem.  It remains feasible even for practically interesting inputs because the set of implicants considered is not the full set.  Espresso makes essential use of the complement of the given function to guide the expansion and reduction processes.

There are also "naive" versions of the algorithm, useful for educational purposes, and there's a chance that an example that shows one bit change after the other is just an illustration of how local search may be used to move from one cover to another, not an illustration of a specific algorithm.

---

In the case of the example above, Espresso would work roughly as follows.  First it will detect that no implicant is essential.  (It's easy to verify that in this case by drawing K-maps of $f$ and $g$.  Espresso, if memory serves, uses a technique due to T. Sasao to identify essential primes.)

It will then find that $11-$, and $-01$ may be expanded from $g$ to $f$ and $g$, while $1-1$ may be expanded from $f$ to $f$ and $g$ (output expansions).  No other expansion is possible.  In particular, no input expansion is possible, as one can verify on the K-maps of $f$ and $g$.  After this expansion, either $1-1$ or $11-$ is redundant because it is jointly covered by the other cubes.  Espresso throws away one of the two.

The resulting solution is a local minimum, whose cubes can be neither expanded nor reduced.  Hence minimization terminates.  The steps you linked to produce a solution of equal cost, but they are not exactly what Espresso would do.  (Again, if memory serves.)  The main difference is that no removal of redundant cubes takes place after the initial expansion phase.

Comment: Hi Fabio, Thank you very much for information. Would you please explain how to do this in ESPRESSO? I am still looking for logical reasoning behind each step.

Comment: @Digvijay See if what I've added is what you are interested.

Comment: Thank you Fabio. I do have ESPRESSO, and have been figuring this out. Could this be done in Logic Friday? When you write "11−, and −01 may be expanded from g to f, while 1−1 may be expanded from to f and g (output expansions)" - how do you infer that this expansion is possible directly from table itself?

Comment: I can't comment on Logic Friday because I've never used it.  Take the expansion of $11-$.  A quick way to do check it's admissible is to split $11-$ into $110$ and $111$.  As far as $f$ goes, they are covered by the second and third cubes of the cover, respectively. This is not what Espresso does, but is adequate for very small examples like this.

Comment: Yes, Espresso will not minimize encoded truth tables. Thank you Fabio.